# Jetty - Can access inside network, but not from outside

Tags: web-applications, jetty

I have a quick question I have been trying for some time to solve myself.
I have a webapp running on jetty which can be viewed from machines on the same network using a web address which points to it. However, it cannot be viewed from outside the network. It is a University network, so I suspect it is a firewall problem, but to save bothering the technical team with yet more questions I wanted to quickly ask, is there any jetty configuration I should check first which would allow  machines on the same network but not machines from an external network, or is it definitely the firewall?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly likely the firewall.

Jetty listens on whatever network interfaces you have on your machine.

I'll restrict my examples to IPv4 as it is still more common, but know that IPv6 based addresses also exist (and might be what your university is using)

Example Interfaces:

**Localhost**

- `127.0.0.1` (localhost) - this will only listen for connections originating from localhost to localhost

**Private Address**

These are a set of IP Addresses that can be assigned to a network interface (such as your personal laptop).  There are several IP ranges that are considered [Private Addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv4_private_addresses), and will allow machines on the same subnet to talk to each other, but will not route beyond that subnet.

- `192.168.0.0` - `192.168.255.255`
- `172.16.0.0` - `172.31.255.255`
- `10.0.0.0` - `10.255.255.255`

If you have an address in these ranges all is not lost though, as your firewall is likely capable of being a gateway between the internet and the university private addresses. (there are many techniques to accomplish this)

**Public Address**

A public address is similar to a private address, but can be exposed to other subnets without much effort.  This doesn't mean that the address you have is the same one others see on the internet though (not getting into detail on this, as its out of scope of the question).

**Meta Address**

There is a special meta address you might see Jetty bound to [`0.0.0.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0).  This means that Jetty is listening on all network interfaces on your machine. (localhost + private + public).  This is the default behavior of jetty and is likely what you have configured.

Before you talk to your University network administrators, it would be wise for you to familiarize yourself with how many network interfaces your machine has, and what each assigned IP address is.  That way you can speak knowledgeably to them about what you have and what your goals are.  Plus, if they approve your request, they'll have everything they need to enable/setup/configure the firewall immediately (without you needing to go get more information for them)

Comment: Thank you Joakim, I really appreciate the time and effort of your port. It explains well, I now know what I need to be doing :). Thanks,